# Java JLabel has white center when it should be filled

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I'm trying to write a bigger program, but right now I'm stuck, and I can't figure out how to solve this problem, which should be easy. I'm creating a matrix of JLabels, and when the frame updates I set the colors of each JLabel from a different matrix. It seems to work well, but the very last JLabel looks weird. It doesn't matter how many JLabels are in my grid, it's always the one in the bottom right corner looking strange.

[image: JPanel View]

I've tried everything to get rid of the little white square in the middle, but nothing works.

Here's the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.tree.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.text.*;


public class Tetris extends JPanel{
private int xsize = 10;
private int ysize = 21;
private JFrame tetrisFrame = new JFrame("Tetris");
private JLabel[][] tetrisField = new JLabel[xsize][ysize];
private byte[][] playGrid = new byte[xsize][ysize];
private byte[][] pieceL = {{-1, 0}, {-1, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}};
private GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();


    public Tetris(){
        tetrisFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        tetrisFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 600));
        tetrisFrame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;

        for (int x = 0; x < xsize; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < ysize; y++) {
                c.gridx = x;
                c.gridy = y;
                JLabel temp = new JLabel();
                temp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 20));
                temp.setOpaque(true);
                temp.setBackground(new Color(0, 255, 0));
                tetrisField[x][y] = temp;
                tetrisFrame.add(temp, c);
            }
        }

        tetrisFrame.add(this, c);
        tetrisFrame.pack();
        tetrisFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(120, 120, 120));
        tetrisFrame.setVisible(true);
        spawnPiece();
    }

    public void spawnPiece() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            playGrid[4+pieceL[i][0]][pieceL[i][1]] = 1;
        }
    }


    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 1050);
        for (int x = 0; x < xsize; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < ysize; y++) {
                if (playGrid[x][y] == 1) {
                    tetrisField[x][y].setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 255));
                } else {
                    tetrisField[x][y].setBackground(new Color(255, 0, 0));

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The white color comes from `g.clearRect()`, if I remove that line the center is grey, same as the background.

I also have a class that runs this. It only creates a new instance of the Tetris class, starts a timer, and repaints.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.io.*;


public class Controller extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private Tetris tetrisView;
    private Timer test;

    public Controller() {
        tetrisView = new Tetris();
        test = new Timer(100, this);
        test.start();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        tetrisView.repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Controller();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because you add all components to `JFrame` and then you add instance of `Tetris` above last `JLabel` :

```
tetrisFrame.add(this, c);
```

You can solve it by moving components to `JPanel`.

Also for custom painting use `paintComponent()` method instead of `paint()`, and call `super.paintComponent()` at start of method instead of `g.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 1050);`.

Comment: I will try that, thanks for finding my error! How do you mean that I should move the components to JPanel?

Comment: I went for another method, but you still answered my original question. Thank you!